# How to Make a PivotTable out of "hierarchical" Excel spreadsheet data

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table

I would like to create a PivotTable out of "hierarchical" data contained in an Excel 2010 worksheet. The data is hierarchical in the sense of a parent/child relationship in a database where, effectively, one "parent" row may have many "child" rows.

I have a large worksheet I compiled as part of a research project. The rows in the worksheet represent legal judgments (cases). In each case, there are one or more legal issues. Part of the project involved classifying the issues in the worksheet. For simplicity, the sheet has three columns for issues, "Issue 1", "Issue 2", "Issue 3".

Here's a simplified example of the worksheet. Note that I have simplified it and there are many other columns.

```
A      B            C  ...  F  G                        H                         I       ...
CASEID APPEAL FROM             ISSUE1                   ISSUE2                    ISSUE3
 C01   Conviction              Evidence-admissibility
 C02   Conviction              Credibility              Fresh evidence
 C03   Acquittal               Credibility              Evidence-misapprehension
 C04   Conviction              Fairness                 Abuse of process          Delay
 C05   Sentence                Credit for time served
```

As you can see, it would be nice to be able to answer questions such as: What are the most prevalent issues on appeals from convictions?

Conceptually, the data I have shown above really has a form of parent/child relationship. Imagine a "Case" table and an "Issue" table where there is a 1:N relationship between the two tables.

Is there a way to get this data into a PivotTable so I can answer questions such as the one I suggested above? I am able to "massage" the data programmatically, but I would prefer to avoid something as crude as creating a new worksheet and flattening it by duplicating rows. In other words, I would rather not transform the above worksheet into this:

```
A      B            C  ...  F  G                        ...
CASEID APPEAL FROM             ISSUE
 C01   Conviction              Evidence-admissibility
 C02   Conviction              Credibility              
 C02   Conviction              Fresh evidence
 C03   Acquittal               Credibility
 C03   Acquittal               Evidence-misapprehension
 C04   Conviction              Fairness
 C04   Conviction              Abuse of process
 C04   Conviction              Delay
 C05   Sentence                Credit for time served
```

Comment: +1 I often have the same question, but end up writing VBA to transpose the data in the way you describe at the end. I assume you want to do this in excel rather than access?

Comment: Exactly right @Raystafarian. If there is an elegant way to manipulate the data without having to duplicate and rearrange it with VBA, I'd love to know.

Answer (score 1):

I would download the Power Query add-in

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/download-microsoft-power-query-for-excel-FX104018616.aspx

... and use the Append function:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/append-queries-HA104149760.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA103993872

Power Query was recently released - it works like recording a macro, but focussed on importing data into Excel and mashing up tables of data.  You design "Query" objects which are reusable and can be edited in script form.

The Append function in Power Query can append rows from one table beneath another in a single operation.

Comment: Thanks Mike. This is a useful answer and a useful tool. The links are to the MS Office page, so they are unlikely to 404, but adding a little bit more information on what this is and how it works would make this a better answer.

Comment: [Getting started with Power Query](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powerbi/archive/2013/07/07/getting-started-with-pq-and-pm.aspx)